# ASP.NET application to display Windows Service progress

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, windows-services

I have a C# Windows Service and an ASP.NET 4.0 web application that are, at the moment, independent of each other and hosted in the same network.

The Windows Service reads from a database, and generates a text file each time it is invoked.

My intention is to

a) Call the Windows Service from the ASP.NET application. 
   After reading a bit, it seems this can be easily done using the Service Controller class.

b) To display live progress of the Windows Service at the client side (browser)

My initial thoughts were to have some kind of global variables inside the Service, that can then be accessed by the remote asp.net app, but I'd like to know what is the best way to do this.

Comment: Why not have the windows service write its status to a database table and then have the asp.net service make periodic calls to read this data. That would be a lot simpler? What if the service crashes, for example? Your global variables, and even the service would not be available then and you'd lose the state.

Comment: Are you only looking to get the "Service Status" of the Windows service or are there other statuses that your service should report?

Comment: I want to report the exact progress.

Say, the total number of records in the table, and the number of records processed.

Comment: @colonel_px - Shared state like that generally requires either a persisted state (such as in a database like dash suggested) or you could host a WCF service from your Windows Service to be able to report the data (I would probably choose this one).

Comment: I vote for WCF as well. Checking status is a separate concern from your database process. The database should not have to be altered or opened with write access or endure write bandwidth hits. Implement a WCF service inside your Windows Service. This also ensures your ASP.NET application can run under the lowest security trust level possible and does not need database access. In short, it minimizes the attack surface and keeps concerns separate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an MSDN article on hosting a WCF service within a Windows Service:

**How to: Host WCF in a Windows Service Using TCP**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc949080.aspx

Comment: Thank you. After reading the responses here and elsewhere, WCF seems to be the way to go.

I shall try this.

Answer (score 2):

The above answer from Kevin seems to be a good idea. But if you really want to have a different service & page without wcf,

I would choose not to go for tying up an asp .net app with a windows service tightly. Instead, I would this.

- Accept some kind of command from the asp .net page into the service which will listen for commands. This could be through a socket or a msmq message etc.,
- Once a command is received, execute the request
- while the execution is in progress update the asp .net page using a COMET approach.

Comment: I can generally agree with this. Perhaps a standard IIS WCF service that communicates via MSMQ to the Windows Service?